# Is there a way to test an IO output using Doctest in Elixir?

Tags: unit-testing, io, elixir, doctest, ex-unit

I'm totally ok with writing a "normal" test capturing the `IO` for this.

Would just like to know if it is possible to use *Doctest*.

An example would be:

```
defmodule CLI do

  @doc """
  Politely says Hello.

  ## Examples

      iex> CLI.main([])
      "Hello dear person." # this would be the expected IO output
  """
  def main(args) do
    IO.puts "Hello dear person."
  end
end

defmodule CLITest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest CLI
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same function as you'd use in a normal test: `ExUnit.CaptureIO.capture_io`. This might not be a function suited for doctests though when you add more functionality to the function.

```
defmodule CLI do
  @doc """
  Politely says Hello.

  ## Examples

      iex> import ExUnit.CaptureIO
      iex> capture_io(fn -> CLI.main([]) end)
      "Hello dear person.\\n"
  """
  def main(args) do
    IO.puts "Hello dear person."
  end
end
```

```
$ mix test
.

Finished in 0.03 seconds
1 test, 0 failures
```

Comment: Yeah, understood.
Yeah, for this specific thing, I think is better to just go for the "actual" test. But this clarifies a bunch.
Thank @Dogbert. =).